# Handling Exceptions (Null?) in Console.Writeline content

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-devops, console.writeline

There has to be a better way to do this?!  I was messing around with ?. etc but could not figure out the proper context for it.  I need to add several more items to the console output, so adding several more nested try-catch is daunting yet do-able.  would have to handle 4 different items that might throw exceptions.

Perhaps, I should be building up the string piece by piece before the writeline statement?

"for now" I have this mess:

```
foreach (WorkItem workItem in workItems){
// write work item to console
try  // ideal both assigned and tagged
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", workItem.Id, 
    workItem.Fields["System.Title"], workItem.Fields["System.WorkItemType"], 
    workItem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"], workItem.Fields["System.State"], 
    workItem.Fields["System.Tags"]);
}
catch (Exception) // at least one not correct, maybe two
{
    try  // is it the assigned?
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", workItem.Id, 
        workItem.Fields["System.Title"], 
        workItem.Fields["System.WorkItemType"], "Unassigned", 
        workItem.Fields["System.State"], workItem.Fields["System.Tags"]);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        try // is it the tags?
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", workItem.Id, 
            workItem.Fields["System.Title"], 
            workItem.Fields["System.WorkItemType"], 
            workItem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"], 
            workItem.Fields["System.State"], "NoTags");

        }
        catch (Exception)  // its both
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", workItem.Id, 
            workItem.Fields["System.Title"], 
            workItem.Fields["System.WorkItemType"], "Unassigned", 
            workItem.Fields["System.State"], "NoTags");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is a question about Exception handling, and I ahve two articles that I like to link on the mater: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | They should get you up to speed on the do's and don'ts

Comment: `workItem?.Fields["x"] ?? "No x"` ? as long as `WorkItem.Fields[..]` doesn't  throw but returns null

Comment: What about using `workItem.Fields.Contains("name") ? workItem.Fields["name"] : "default"` instead.  Assuming that `WorkItem` is `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem`

Comment: @juharr it is             // Create instance of WorkItemTrackingHttpClient using VssConnection
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
So I tried this format: workItem.Fields.Contains("System.AssignedTo")? workItem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"] :"Unassigned"   But ran into CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>'

Comment: @Selvin tried your proposal but it must be throwing. Unhandled Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at AzureDevOpsApp.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: So this is Dictionary... The obviously use TryGetValue

Comment: @Selvin No it's a [`FieldCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb171991%28v%3dvs.120%29) which only has `TryGetById`.

Comment: @DavidElgstuen just slap a `ToString` in there `workItem.Fields.Contains("name") ? workItem.Fields["name"].ToString() : "default"`.  Although the mention of `KeyValuePari<string, object>` is odd.

Comment: @juharr The above class in the link is out of date. You can refer to current [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi.workitemtrackinghttpclientbase.getworkitemsasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet). The Fields property for the workItem is a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on the discussion of the comments. I would like to summary the solution as below.
Thank juharr and Selvin for sharing ideas.

1,Since Fields.Contains("") throws the error. You can use `workItem.Fields.ContainsKey()`. The the example code is as below:

```
workItem.Fields.ContainsKey("name") ? workItem.Fields["name"] : "default"
```

2, use `TryGetValue()`

```
workItem.Fields.TryGetValue("System.AssignedTo", out Object identityOjbect)? identityOjbect:"not exist"
```

Comment: Option 1 did work for me however I couldn't get option 2 to work.
Console.WriteLine("{0}" "{1}" "{2}" "{3}", workItem.Id, workItem.Fields["System.Title"], workItem.Fields["System.WorkItemType"], (workItem.Fields.TryGetValue("System.AssignedTo", out Object identityOjbect) ? identityOjbect : "not exist"));


has a syntax error missing a ',' expected

Comment: @David Elgstuen the format should be in a single double quote. Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", workItem.Id,...}. `"{0}" "{1}" "{2}" "{3}"` is not a valid format